# Accessing only the values in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

```
wordDict = {'y': 1, 'H': 1, 'e': 1}
```

The above is what I need to get just the value from. I am supposed to mark whether or not each word I have to evaluate is unique or not, which depends on if the values are 1 or above. How would I get access to only the value? I have tried wordDict[0][0] to get the first element of the whole array and then the first element within the dictionary, but that does not work.

```
import collections;

def main():
    reading = read_file();
    uniqueOrNot = isUnique(reading);
    print uniqueOrNot;

def read_file():
    with open('BWA5.in') as fp:
        lines = fp.read().split();
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function

def isUnique(words):
    wordDict = [dict(collections.Counter(word)) for word in words];
    for wordDict in wordDicts:
        values = wordDict.values()
        unique = all(value == 1 for value in values)
    print wordDict;


main();
```

Comment: It is a dictionary, not a list so you have to index using the keys. Alternatively, you can get keys and values in a tuple with `wordDict.items()` or the values with `wordDict.values()` (keep in mind that dictionaries are unordered)

Comment: Ok so if I have to just label the word unique or not unique and that all depends on if that particular word has a letter that appears twice (ex: hey = unique but apple = not unique) how would I compare the value next to each letter within the dictionary without having to access the key?

Answer (score 0):

Get the values by

```
values = wordDict.values()
```

Now the unique thingy,

```
unique = all(value == 1 for value in values)
```

Now `unique` is a Boolean value holding True/False.

We could have also done:

```
notUnique = any(value > 1 for value in values)
```

This takes into consideration any 0 frequency letters which you might or might not have, depending on your algorithm.

For a list of dictionaries for multiple words, you can traverse through them all at a time by using a loop.

***EDIT***:

Final code:

```
import collections;

def main():
    reading = read_file();
    uniqueOrNot = isUnique(reading);
    print uniqueOrNot;

def read_file():
    with open('BWA5.in') as fp:
        lines = fp.read().split();
    fp.close(); #close file
    return lines; #return lines to main function

def isUnique(words):
    wordDicts = [dict(collections.Counter(word)) for word in words];
    for wordDict in wordDicts:
        values = wordDict.values()
        unique = all(value == 1 for value in values)
        print unique;


main();
```

Comment: I get this error when I try to use wordDict.values() AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: It is working fine for me. Are you sure about the wordDict being a dictionary and not a list? By any chance did you initialize it with []?

Comment: Yup. There's your error. It is an array after all. But in the question you made it a single dict. Anyway, let me modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: that still gives me the same error because of the   .values()

Comment: Could you please update the question with an exact image of what your wordDicts is storing? Or maybe a small portion if the size is too big. As you mentioned an array of dicts.

Comment: Runs absolutely fine with your updated wordDicts.  Here. https://ideone.com/gKBsfD

Comment: i put my actual code in my question. I know the error is within isUnique()

Comment: Lol. Pretty silly mistake. Please rename wordDict to wordDicts in your first line in isUnique()

Comment: I cross verified. My code works with python 2 as well as 3. So that isn't the issue here.

Comment: (Here is what i get) {'p': 1, 's': 1, 'o': 2, 'n': 1}
None

Comment: Is the code showing any error?
Then I'll go ahead and edit your actual code and post the final code in my answer.

Comment: You get that because you are not printing the unique.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Would it be similar code to get the unique letters to be printed? For example, diddle would print out: i e l

Comment: You might have to throw in a few extra lines in there, but it wont be much of an issue. I suggest you to look at "list comprehension" in python. Makes your code short, simple and elegant.